# Change region to (English) Australia

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How do I change the region to (English) Australia on Windows Mobile using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set what region?  The region just for your app?  The CF has no support for Thread.CurrentCulture, so you have to maintain your own [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=VS.90).aspx) and [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=VS.90).aspx) but it's certainly not difficult.

If you mean device-wide (like you would through the control panel) then P/Invoke [SetUserDefaultLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906279.aspx).  Note what MSDN says about broadcasting a WM_SETTINGCHANGE after making the call.